# Googlemap class is not recognizable

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I am trying to code a mapview-based app. In accordance with the tutorial, I had to download google play service first. After downloading it I still can not define a variable of type `GoogleMap`. for an example, `private GoogleMap map`. The datatype `Googlemap` is not recognizable by eclipse. Any suggestions for this problem?

Comment: include the `google library` to your project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to include the **Google Playservices library** to your Project.

Here is the Steps from [**`GoogleDoc`**](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=19nQzvKP-CVLd7_VrpwnHfl-AE9fjbJySowONZZtNHzw) How to add the Google Play Services library

1. Add the Google Play Services project into your Eclipse workspace.

> Click File -> Import..., select Android -> Existing Android Code into Workspace
>       Browse to and select /extras/google/google_play_services/libproject/google-play-services_lib

1. To add the dependency to Google Play Services into your project

> Project -> Properties -> Android -> Library, Add -> google-play-services_lib